# Ubuntu 18.04 install kernel-headers-$(uname -r) always fail?

Tags: ubuntu, header, kernel, apt

I'm using ubuntu18.04, I've apt update && apt upgrade and installed gcc/g++, libxxxx, etc. Then I:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

OK, it exists, but:

```
apt-get install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kernel-headers-4.15.0-50-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'kernel-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'kernel-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You should check [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064674/linux-headers-reinstall). And try to use sudo

Comment: Thanks, after installing "apt install linux-headers-generic", use 4.10.74xxx version in Makefile will work"